# accuracy of float32

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy

To reduce the filesize, I'm trying to save `float64` data to file in `float32`. The data values generally range from 1e-12 to 10. I tested the accuracy loss when converting `float64` to `float32`.

```
print np.finfo('float32')
```

shows

```
Machine parameters for float32
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision=  6   resolution= 1.0000000e-06
machep=   -23   eps=        1.1920929e-07
negep =   -24   epsneg=     5.9604645e-08
minexp=  -126   tiny=       1.1754944e-38
maxexp=   128   max=        3.4028235e+38
nexp  =     8   min=        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looks `float32` has a resolution of `1e-6` and the abs value is valid down to as small as `1.2e-38`.

```
import numpy as np

x = 2.0*np.random.rand(100) - 1.0 # make random numbers in [-1, 1]

print('x.dtype: %s'%(x.dtype)) # outputs float64

print('number :  max_error  max_relative_error')
for i in xrange(-40, 1):
    y = x * 10**i
    print('1e%-4d:  %s'%(i, np.max(np.abs(y - y.astype('f4').astype('f8')))))
```

The results are

```
number:    max_error       max_relative_error
1e-40 :    6.915620e-46    6.915620e-06
1e-39 :    6.910361e-46    6.910361e-07
1e-38 :    6.949349e-46    6.949349e-08
1e-37 :    4.816590e-45    4.816590e-08
1e-36 :    4.303771e-44    4.303771e-08
1e-35 :    3.518621e-43    3.518621e-08
1e-34 :    5.165854e-42    5.165854e-08
1e-33 :    3.660088e-41    3.660088e-08
1e-32 :    3.660088e-40    3.660088e-08
1e-31 :    4.097193e-39    4.097193e-08
1e-30 :    4.615068e-38    4.615068e-08
1e-29 :    3.696983e-37    3.696983e-08
1e-28 :    2.999860e-36    2.999860e-08
1e-27 :    4.723454e-35    4.723454e-08
1e-26 :    3.801082e-34    3.801082e-08
1e-25 :    3.062408e-33    3.062408e-08
1e-24 :    4.876378e-32    4.876378e-08
1e-23 :    3.779378e-31    3.779378e-08
1e-22 :    3.144592e-30    3.144592e-08
1e-21 :    4.991049e-29    4.991049e-08
1e-20 :    3.949261e-28    3.949261e-08
1e-19 :    3.002761e-27    3.002761e-08
1e-18 :    5.162480e-26    5.162480e-08
1e-17 :    4.135703e-25    4.135703e-08
1e-16 :    3.282146e-24    3.282146e-08
1e-15 :    4.722129e-23    4.722129e-08
1e-14 :    3.863295e-22    3.863295e-08
1e-13 :    3.375549e-21    3.375549e-08
1e-12 :    4.011790e-20    4.011790e-08
1e-11 :    4.011790e-19    4.011790e-08
1e-10 :    3.392060e-18    3.392060e-08
1e-9  :    5.471206e-17    5.471206e-08
1e-8  :    4.072652e-16    4.072652e-08
1e-7  :    3.496987e-15    3.496987e-08
1e-6  :    5.662626e-14    5.662626e-08
1e-5  :    4.412957e-13    4.412957e-08
1e-4  :    3.482083e-12    3.482083e-08
1e-3  :    5.597344e-11    5.597344e-08
1e-2  :    4.620014e-10    4.620014e-08
1e-1  :    3.540690e-09    3.540690e-08
1e0   :    2.817751e-08    2.817751e-08
```

The relative error is at the order of `1e-8` for values above 1e-38, lower than `1e-6` proposed by `np.finfo` and the error is still acceptable even if the value if lower than the `tiny` value of `np.finfo`.

Looks it's safe to save my data in `float32`, but I'm curious about the test looks inconsistent with the results of `np.finfo`?

Answer (score 6):

Numbers that low are in the subnormal range.  Basically, the exponent doesn't have enough range to get sufficiently low, so you're gradually losing significant bits as values get lower.  This is called "gradual underflow".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Answer (score 1):

Since machine floating point epsilon is 1.1920929e-07, rounding would get you relative error within half of that for normal floats: 5.9604645e-8. However, when you get smaller than 1.1754944e-38, you have denormalized numbers, which instead have an absolute error of 1.4012985e-45.